# Duplicate rows in mat-table inside mat-tab

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a parent component with a mat-tab-group that has several tabs. Each tab's content is a child component that has some static data and some dynamic data that is in mat-table. Tab's content (child components) is eagerly loaded.

The parent component is responsible for synchronizing when child components update their data. This is done by passing observable to child components that emit value each second; on this mark, child components contact API to get new data for their tables. API is standard OData API that works correctly.

This is how components are organized:

```
<mat-tab-group>
 <mat-tab label="Tab-1">
  <app-component-one [input]="observable$"></app-component-one>
 </mat-tab>
 <mat-tab label="Tab-2">
  <app-component-two [input]="observable$"></app-component-two>
 </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

Here is the picture of how that looks:
[This is how table looks before switching to another tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xryR.png)

Problem:
Tab 'Details' has table with 3 rows. The user then switches the tab to 'Errors' or 'Logs', stays there for more than one second (so all child components update their data), and then returns to 'Details'. Table on that tab shows all original rows (3 of them) and every row that new API call returned (let's say 3 more) - 6 in total. However, new rows should entirely replace old rows.

When I look into table's data source there are only 3 new rows (not all 6 that are rendered). Mat-tooltips, mat-animations, mat-buttons etc. that are in every row work only on 3 new rows (and not on 3 original rows) as if mat-table is not aware old rows still exist (are rendered).

[This is how table looks after switching to another tab and going back](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYmsw.png)

Circled blue are 'old' rows on which mat-tooltips, row clicks, mat-animations do not work. Circled red are 'new' rows that work exactly as expected.
Does anyone have any idea why is this happening? Troubleshooting tips would also be very appreciated. Unfortunately, I was unable to reproduce the same behaviour in stackblitz.

Comment: It's hard to say what your issue is. You're saying about duplicate rows in the title, then about some API calls that we don't know anything about, then about rows that are rendered but are not in the DataSource. Can you prepare a stackblitz and tell as exactly whats wrong with it? Otherwise it's really hard to help.

Comment: I edited for clarity. I was unable to reproduce the same issue using stackblitz.

Comment: Thanks - that seems much clearer now. Your issue might be with eager loading of the tab content. By default, mat-tab-group removes items from the DOM while they are not in active tab to increase performance. I haven't dug into internals of mat-table, but it might rely on objects being in the DOM. Since you're doing stuff asynchronously, some updates might be happening when table is not in DOM, so old rows are not being deleted. Try using lazy-loading for mat-tab-content: https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/overview#lazy-loading

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't use lazy-loading due to some other restrictions.